# Detect a star in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

A time ago I made a Python script to detect stars in an image on given coordinates using OpenCV. Unfortunately, OpenCV isn't recognising as well as I would need it.
I have now made a function that tries to find the center of a star with a spiral search of the brightest pixel. With another spiral search, I want to color each pixel bigger as a defined value to be plain white. So far this works. 
The problem is that I need to use quite large search regions because the stars have very big differences in diameter. I get the following result. For now, I break my loop when a pixel value < 1 is read from the image. As the spiral search goes in square and the stars are elliptical, this isn't really working and I got cut of parts from the star.
Is there any way to detect a wider gap with values < 1, something like 1 round of black pixels around the star and then break the loop? As the start coordinates aren't 100% in the center and the star size differs from star to star a break after x black pixels isn't possible, unfortunately.

[image: This is a result]

The star in the middle is the star is of interest. 
I'm doing all the image work with PIL in this script

```
    for i in range(max(X, Y) ** 2):
    if (-X / 2 < x <= X / 2) and (-Y / 2 < y <= Y / 2):
        current_X = source_X + x
        current_Y = source_Y + y
        pixel_value = starfiel_gray.getpixel((current_X, current_Y))
        print(current_X, current_Y, pixel_value)
        if pixel_value > background_threshold:
            starmask.putpixel((current_X, current_Y), 255)
    if x == y or (x < 0 and x == -y) or (x > 0 and x == 1 - y):
        dx, dy = -dy, dx
    x, y = x + dx, y + dy
```

Thank you for suggestions :-)

Kevin

Comment: just an idea: [blur and] downsample (factor of 1/10 or so) and do a rough search on that low-res image to detect interesting regions, and then use a slower algorithm on the regions to find the stars

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. For the downsampled I would also need to detect the edge of the star, which is the same problem as in my full resolution image.
Time isn't the problem, so I changed from OpenCV to this. A good detection is much mor critical.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I add up all pixel values of a round, if the sum does not change (or is below a set threshold) after a new round, the loop will be aborted.
Seems to work quite well so far.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).